# Including a header containing a class in a .cpp file does not work as expected

Tags: c++

I wrote a testing class in a header like this:

*File.h*

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

class File {
    fstream stream;
public:
    File(string path);
    ~File();
};

File::File(string path) {
    stream.open(path);
}

File::~File() {
    stream.close();
}

#endif // FILE_H
```

And in another file I included and used it like this:

*t.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "/home/unlimiter/Documents/programming/modules/cpp/uio/File.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    File f("/home/unlimiter/tst");
}
```

Why does errors occur (like that fstream is not defined) when I do that?

> I tested writing the class inside 't.cpp' and that works fine

Comment: `#include <fstream>` should be in `file.h`

Comment: @JVApen same problem...

Comment: `std::fstream`, as this object doesn't live in the global namespace?

Comment: @JVApen Yes, that solved the "fstream not defined problem" at least. But there are many left problems

Comment: Also, just in case you include this header in multiple places, you should separate the declaration from the implementation.  Do this by moving all the `File::...` blocks to a `File.cpp` file, then include the header in that file.

Comment: Guys, don't answer in the comments!!

Comment: @JVApen -- your comment is essentially correct, but `std::fstream` is not an **object**; it's a **type**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is indeed no such thing as `fstream`. It is spelt `std::fstream`.
2. Same for `std::string`.
3. Some people will tell you to work around this by writing `using namespace std`. [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/560648) (if only because you'd need to do it in a header, which is considered ungood).
4. It would be better to put those `#include`s in the file that needs them, i.e. the header itself. Otherwise you're relying on including a bunch of things together for any of it to work (which is also considered ungood).
5. Try not to use absolute paths in `#include` directives: it makes your source code difficult to move around your computer, or to other computers. This kind of thing is better managed by your compilation environment / bulid system.
6. Now you need to move your function definitions into the `.cpp` file (or perhaps a new `File.cpp`!) because as soon as you include your header in more than one translation unit, the linker will complain about multiple definitions.